# iOS App Store Update 32 Bit Application to 64 Bit only -> 32 Bit version still available as fallback in App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, 64-bit

**Situation**

I have developed an application which is currently working for both architectures 32 and 64 bit. This application was approved by Apple and is available in App Store.

During development new features I use some precompiled libraries which were only compiled for 64 bit architecture.

**Question:**

When I apply a new application version to the App Store it is clear that the application would only run for 64 bit devices.

But is the (old) 32 bit version still available for 32 bit devices?

Comment: What does your *Valid Architectures" say? Is it still "arm64 armv7 armv7s"?

Comment: @Blaise what u suggest? my client need updated code and he is using iphone 5.